# Coroutine crashes app when run from HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded (Unity AdMob)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to run the noAdsReviveCountdown() coroutine as a reward for the player finishing a rewarded video ad but it keeps crashing the app when it hits the call. Commenting out this call causes the video ad works as expected. 

 Logs from Xcode just give me "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type Il2CppExceptionWrapper" 

 Can I not run a coroutine in the reward handler? I've tried commenting out various parts of the function but it seems even the bare minimum of the coroutine crashes the app.

```
// No Ad Revive Countdown function - after 3 seconds the game will resume
public IEnumerator noAdsReviveCountdown() {

    continueButton.interactable = false;
    continueText.gameObject.SetActive (false);
    adReviveButton.gameObject.SetActive (false);
    noAdsReviveCountdownText.gameObject.SetActive (true);

    timeLeft = 3;
    while (timeLeft >= 0) {
        noAdsReviveCountdownText.text = timeLeft.ToString();
        noAdsReviveCountdownAnim.ResetTrigger ("CountdownTrigger");
        noAdsReviveCountdownAnim.SetTrigger ("CountdownTrigger");
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1.0f);
        timeLeft--;
    }
    if (timeLeft < 0) {
        var balls = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("ball");
        foreach (var ball in balls) {
            Destroy (ball);
        }
        noAdsReviveCountdownText.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        continueButton.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Reproduced on my game. It's about the coroutine too, If you have a solution I'll glad to hear it!